# How to remove parenthesis, comma and Quotation mark

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print chessboard with "."(dot) and "*"asterisk. Suppose input is 33 i need to print 3 X 3 chessboard.

my code works something like this:

```
32
('*', '.')
('.', '*')
*.
```

I don't know why there is  parenthesis, comma and Quotation mark.

**here's is my code:**

```
row = raw_input()                   
row = int(row)
count = 0

a = "*"
b = "."

while True:
    count = count +1 




    if ((int(str(row)[0]))%2 == 0) and ((int(str(row)[1]))%2 == 0): 
        print (a,b) * (int(str(row)[1])/2)
        print (b,a) * (int(str(row)[1])/2)

    elif ((int(str(row)[0]))%2 != 0) and ((int(str(row)[1]))%2 == 0):
        print (a,b) * (int(str(row)[1])/2)
        print (b,a) * (int(str(row)[1])/2)


    elif ((int(str(row)[0]))%2 == 0) and ((int(str(row)[1]))%2 != 0):
        print (a,b) * (int(str(row)[1])/2), "*"
        print (b,a) * (int(str(row)[1])/2), "."

    elif ((int(str(row)[0]))%2 != 0) and ((int(str(row)[1]))%2 != 0):   
        print (a,b) * (int(str(row)[1])/2), "*"
        print (b,a) * (int(str(row)[1])/2), "."


    if (int(str(row)[0]))%2 == 0 and count == (int(str(row)[0]))/2 :
        break

    elif (int(str(row)[0]))%2 != 0 and count == (int(str(row)[0]))/2:
        print "*."
        break
```

I used logic "a" * 4 will print aaaa but it is not printing like that!

---

P.S. I know few stuff are still not working like single digit boards and any board which contains 1.

Comment: Your code would be a lot nicer if you parsed the digits of your input into separate row and column variables right away, rather than repeating the same code to split the digits in the later lines.

Comment: @Blckknght Sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `(a,b) * number` use `(a+b) * number`. `(a,b)` is a tuple whereas `(a+b)` is a string.